# Check if variables are one greater than the previous in batch?

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a simple poker game in batch and need help checking for straights in a hand where:        The second set of code is how my cards are generated (there is another block of this for the second card, flop cards and so forth)

```
%card% = player's first card
%card2% = player's second card
%fcard% %fcard2% and %fcard3% = the three flop cards
%tcard% = the turn card
%rcard% = the river card

set /a card=%random% %% 13 + 1
set /a suit=%random% %% 4 + 1
if %card%==13 set card=Ace
if %card%==12 set card=King
if %card%==11 set card=Queen
if %card%==10 set card=Jack
if %card%==9 set card=Ten
if %card%==8 set card=Nine
if %card%==7 set card=Eight
if %card%==6 set card=Seven
if %card%==5 set card=Six
if %card%==4 set card=Five
if %card%==3 set card=Four
if %card%==2 set card=Three
if %card%==1 set card=Two
if %suit%==1 set suit=Spades
if %suit%==2 set suit=Clubs
if %suit%==3 set suit=Hearts
if %suit%==4 set suit=Diamonds
```

I need to be able to check for any straight (5 cards in a row such as 9,10,J,Q,K)

Comment: What are `%card%` , `%fcard%` ?  This not how you set variable values.Are the values of card variables holding some commands?

Comment: You need to show us REAL CODE.  Not pseudo code.

Comment: Which cards need to be in order? What values do the variables have?

Comment: I have edited and put in the actual code used to generate cards hope that helps

Comment: Can't an ACE be high and low?

Comment: yes but this is not how i am attempting to look for straights this is simply how my cards are generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "cardSet=_A23456789TJQKA"
set "i=0"
for %%a in (Ace Two Three Four Five Six Seven Eight Nine Ten Jack Queen King Ace) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set "name[!i!]=%%a"
)

:nextSet
echo/
set /P "set=Enter a set of 5 cards separated by spaces: "
if errorlevel 1 goto :EOF

set "i=0"
for %%a in (%set%) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set "card[!i!]=%%a"
)

:Sort the cards
set "change="
for /L %%i in (1,1,4) do (
   set /A j=%%i+1
   for %%j in (!j!) do (
      if !card[%%i]! gtr !card[%%j]! set /A change=card[%%i],card[%%i]=card[%%j],card[%%j]=change
   )
)
if defined change goto :Sort the cards

rem Re-assemble the set in order with letters
set "set1="
for /L %%i in (1,1,5) do (
   for %%j in (!card[%%i]!) do set "set1=!set1!!cardSet:~%%j,1!"
)

rem Special case: Ace is greater than King
set "set2=%set1%"
if "%set2:~0,1%" equ "A" set "set2=%set2:~1%A"

rem Test for straights
set "straight="
for /L %%i in (1,1,10) do if not defined straight (
   if "%set1%" equ "!cardSet:~%%i,5!" set /A "straight=%%i+4"
   if "%set2%" equ "!cardSet:~%%i,5!" set /A "straight=%%i+4"
)

if defined straight (
   echo Yes, ending at !name[%straight%]!
) else (
   echo No
)

goto nextSet
```

Output example:

```
Enter a set of 5 cards separated by spaces: 8 2 7 10 13
No

Enter a set of 5 cards separated by spaces: 8 5 7 4 6
Yes, ending at Eight

Enter a set of 5 cards separated by spaces: 9 12 11 13 10
Yes, ending at King

Enter a set of 5 cards separated by spaces: 11 10 1 13 12
Yes, ending at Ace

Enter a set of 5 cards separated by spaces: 3 2 5 4 1
Yes, ending at Five
```

Comment: Thanks aacini this is very helpful however I need to know how to do this with variable that were already defined not with user input.  Im sure its a very simple change to the code

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. The required change is so simple that you will do it by yourself for sure... May I ask you to upvote and select this answer?

Comment: I clicked upvote but I have less than 15 rep so it doesnt count